# How to display the results of a ref cursor using SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure with several cursors.  They are defined as IN OUT parameters.  I would like to display the result of the cursors using SQL Developer.
This is an example of the stored procedure:

```
SET serveroutput on;
DECLARE
         p_input_stream       VARCHAR2(200);
        p_msg_code            NUMBER;
         p_msg_parms                         VARCHAR2(200);
         p_return_code                       NUMBER;
         p_trailer_cur                    sl_globals.curtype_weak;

 BEGIN
    /* Assign values to IN parameters */
    p_input_stream := '24954286Mnull|5155035|2|436|SCAN|47720|XTRA|0105||5155035||||N|~|\r';
    p_trailer_cur := null;

EXEC TRAILER_INFO(p_input_stream, 
        p_msg_code, p_msg_parms, p_return_code, 
        p_trailer_cur)

 /* Display OUT parameters */
    dbms_output.put_line('p_msg_code: ' || p_msg_code);
    dbms_output.put_line('p_msg_parms: ' || p_msg_parms);
    dbms_output.put_line('p_return_code: ' || p_return_code);
```

I have tried creating a refcursor variable and using it in place of `p_trailer_cur` like this

```
VARIABLE trailer_cur refcursor;
 EXEC TRAILER_INFO(p_input_stream, 
        p_msg_code, p_msg_parms, p_return_code, 
        :trailer_cur)
 print trailer_cur;
```

I get the error:

> SP2-0552: Bind Varialbe "trailer_cur is not declared.

The variable is declared so I don't understand the error.

Comment: What is `EXEC` in your PL/SQL block? There is no such command in PL/SQL.

Comment: EXEC is a SQLPlus command - it's not part of the plsql language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways SQL Developer supports this - the GUI and the Code.

**The GUI**

If you execute your stored procedure from the Code Editor, find the stored procedure in the tree, click on it, use the Execute button - we'll grab ALL of your output, and show it below in the output panels:

[image]

**And your attempt, the Code:**

If you're in the SQL Worksheet and you have your anonymous block, you can run it with F5, including your print command.

Like so -

```
create or replace function get_emps(dno in number) return sys_refcursor
    is
      return_value sys_refcursor;
    begin
      open return_value for
        select * from employees where department_id = dno;
      return return_value;
    end;
    /



 var rc refcursor
 exec :rc := get_emps(90)

 print rc
```

[image]

Comment: Since I have several parameters to output, I would like to do it from the Worksheet.  However, when I run it from the Worksheet, I get the error: **Bind Varialbe "trailer_cur is not declared.**  The cursor is an IN OUT parameter.

Comment: @GloriaSantin your code block isn't complete? it shows some of what you're running, but not everything? Plus I don't have access to TRAILER_INFO() - can you try the code I shared? if you don't have an HR.EMPLOYEES table, then change the cursor query to whatever you have laying around

Comment: If it is an IN OUT parameter that is the cursor, what is the syntax to output the cursor?

Comment: ...to print it? should be the same, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22505596/1156452

Comment: fwiw, SQLDev handles it either way for you, since you tagged sqldev, i showed you the GUI solution, it's literally 'push button' ready