# Can I display the result of dynamic SQL select statement in SQL Developer's grid?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle's SQL Developer, I can execute a "dynamic" SQL select statement in the *Script Output* pane with something like:

```
script
  var tabName = 'all_users';
  sqlcl.setStmt('select * from ' + tabName);
  sqlcl.run();
/
```

Now, I am wondering if it is possible to execute a dynamic select statement such that its result is displayed in the result grid.

Comment: i think you can wrap your dynamic sql in a pipelined table function and create a view around it using the table operator

Comment: This assumes that the dynamic sql statement always returns the same number, names and data types of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

SqlDev is implemented in Java which includes Nashorn scripting engine. Therefore, you can basically execute JDBC in your Nashorn script. Here is one way to do it.

Paste

```
select REGIONS,
COUNTRIES,
LOCATIONS,
DEPARTMENTS,
JOBS,
EMPLOYEES,
JOB_HISTORY,
TM_USER_INFO,
USER_ROLES,
PAYMENT_PRICE_SHOP,
SHOP_USER from dual
```

into your worksheet.

Open "Code Outline" panel. Type "arbori", or open the following "querySQL.arbori" file:

```
include "std.arbori"

prelude: runOnce -> {
    var ConnectionResolver = Java.type('oracle.dbtools.db.ConnectionResolver');  
    var connectionList = ConnectionResolver.getConnectionNames();
    var conn = ConnectionResolver.getConnection('IdeConnections%23local_hr');
}

queries: [node) column -> {
    var node = tuple.get('node');
    var table = target.input.substring(
            target.src[node.from].begin,
            target.src[node.to-1].end
        );    
    var query = 'select * from ' + table;
    var ps = conn.createStatement();
    var rs = ps.executeQuery(query);
    while( rs.next() )
        print(rs.getString(1));

}
```

It outputs the first column of each table to the standard java output

[image]
, so it would require some reverse engineering to get a handle to the SqlDev script output panel and channel the result there.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL can be displayed in an Oracle SQL Developer grid using a function returning a ref cursor (sort of), a polymorphic table function (18c+), or Oracle Data Cartridge (requires custom PL/SQL packages and types).

### Function Returning Ref Cursor

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54487066/409172), the output from a function returning a ref cursor can be displayed in the "Output Variables" window. The example from the answer used static SQL, but it's pretty easy to make it dynamic:

```
create or replace function refcursor_function return sys_refcursor as
  c sys_refcursor;
begin
  open c for 'select * from all_objects';
  return c;
end;
/
```

The downside is that getting the results takes a few more clicks than a normal query, and the Output Variables grid is not nearly as powerful as the regular results grid. If you just need a window for viewing and copying and pasting, Output Variables is good enough. But it doesn't allow any advanced GUI features.

### Polymorphic Table Function

Since Oracle 18c, you can create a polymorphic table function that accepts input and has variable output. You have to program how to handle the tables and columns, but if you just need simple pass-through logic it's not that difficult. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101596/409172) for an example of a query that returns every column from a table excluding specific columns. The results are "regular" SQL as far as any program knows, and will work in any grid GUI.

### Oracle Data Cartridge

My open source program [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4) can run dynamic SQL in SQL. After you download and install the packages and types, you can write a SQL statement that generates another SQL statement. If you need to use PL/SQL to generate the query, you may need to use a PL/SQL WITH function. Like the polymorphic table function, the results look like normal SQL and will work in any grid.

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        --Query that builds another query.
        select replace(
            q'!
                select * from #TABLE_NAME#
            !', '#TABLE_NAME#', table_name) sql_statement
        from
        (
            --Enter your script here that returns a table name to select from.
            select 'ALL_USERS' table_name
            from dual
        )
    ]'
));
```

You may want to add some details about what exactly you're trying to do and why; that might help narrow down the possible solutions.

Comment: The few more mouse clicks required by the function that returns a ref cursor is what caused me to ask this question. I am already able to print the dynamic SQL text somewhere (shell, dbms_output, even Excel etc) and then copy/paste it to the SQL editor. So no real benefit here. The other approaches look great at first sight, but Oracle parses the dynamic SQL text *once* at the function's first invocation and then does not recognize if the SQL text has changed on subsequence invocations. So, these are not really suitable for my purposes as well.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I do appreciate the time you took to answer my question.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I'm not sure about the PTF solution, but I just modified Method4 to force a hard-parse on every execution. (The program had that functionality before but was not consistently using it among all four functions.)

Comment: I just skimmed over your github repository. The purge of the SQL statement does indeed look promising. But give me some time to evaluate it, I won't probably come around it during the next week.

Comment: I am impressed by your work and so far this seems to be the only way to display a dynamic sql statement's result in SQL developer. Unfortunately, the execution of `dbms_shared_pool.purge`  (which is central to your solution) requires non standard privileges that are not granted in all environments I am working in. As much as I like your solution, I think it's a workaround for a functionality that SQL developer almost provides and could provide. In summary, I wait for a "real" SQL developer solution so that I don't yet accept your valuable contribution as answer to my question.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Thanks. I understand your concern about `dbms_shared_pool` - I'm trying to find ways to simplify or reduce the permissions but have been unsuccessful so far.