# How do you display the value of a refcursor in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been trying to view a resultset from a stored procedure call in SQL Developer, but all I can see in "Script Output" tab are the result set's column names. The same code in Toad displays the records in "Grid" but I'm having trouble displaying the same output in SQL Developer.

Code I'm using as follows:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE test_proc (
                          r_recordset      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
      sql_stmt   CLOB := NULL;
    
    BEGIN
      sql_stmt := 
        'select * from test_table';
      OPEN r_recordset FOR sql_stmt;
    END;
```

then

```
set serveroutput on;
variable Out_Ref_Cursor refcursor;
EXECUTE test_proc(:Out_Ref_Cursor);
print :Out_Ref_Cursor;
```

I've turn on DBMS output and connected it to the database but there's absolutely nothing displayed in that window. Buffer size is 20000. Like  this answer suggests: [Printing the value of a variable in SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887413/printing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-sql-developer/7889380#7889380)
I'm wondering if I'm missing a setting or a view. FYI: total number of records in test_table are 48.

I have also tried

```
DECLARE
Out_Ref_Cursor refcursor
BEGIN
test_proc (:Out_Ref_Cursor);
dbms_output.put_line(Out_Ref_Cursor);
END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display the results of a ref cursor using SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486796/how-to-display-the-results-of-a-ref-cursor-using-sql-developer)

Comment: no, I've tried everything in that answer but didn't work. that answer also relates to a function and not a store proc so I assumed that's why it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have everything I need to test your issue except for your TEST_TABLE. Your example, re-written for HR.COUNTRIES

[image]

Comment: how strange... what's your SQL Developer version no.? mine is 21.4

Comment: a year or 2 newer than that but this code hasn't changed in years. like i said, what's in your table? blobs, clobs, XMLTYPE, something more exotic than a varchar2 or integer?

Comment: add this to your 3 lines of code that you're running 'set serveroutput on'

Comment: yeah I tried that already. didn't work

Comment: something is up with your ENV then - if you want more help, come over to our forums 
 https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/sql_developer?tags=sql-developer

Answer (score 0):

Solved! uninstalling and installing a new version of SQL Developer with a new JDK did the trick