# How to display REF_CURSOR out Parameter from a procedure -Oracle12C

Tags: oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor

Am i doing anything wrong here , i am trying to display the SYS_REFCURSOR out values in DBMS_OUTPUT.
here is my code so far, its giving invalid cursor exception . can someone help me on this .

```
DECLARE
out_dcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
snumber                     VARCHAR2(5);
   inumber                 VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN

 my_proc(out_dcursor, 'INPUT_VALUE', NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,'INPUT_VALUE2', NULL, NULL);
 
 loop
 fetch out_dcursor into snumber
           ,inumber;
 exit when out_dcursor%NOTFOUND;
 end loop;
 
END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL print out ref cursor returned by a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822241/pl-sql-print-out-ref-cursor-returned-by-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: "Invalid cursor" errors don't seem to be relevant if your question is about how to print the results of a cursor. Test it with a valid cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You're complaining about `dbms_output` and *invalid cursor*, but - there's no first term in code you posted, and you didn't say which part returns the second one.

Here's example which shows something that *works*. See if you can use it with your code, as we don't know what `my_proc` is, accepts, does nor returns.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure my_proc (par_rc out sys_refcursor) is
  2  begin
  3    open par_rc for select deptno, dname from dept;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    rc       sys_refcursor;
  3    l_deptno dept.deptno%type;
  4    l_dname  dept.dname%type;
  5  begin
  6    my_proc(rc);
  7    loop
  8      fetch rc into l_deptno, l_dname;
  9      exit when rc%notfound;
 10      dbms_output.put_Line(l_deptno ||' '|| l_dname);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
10 ACCOUNTING
20 RESEARCH
30 SALES
40 OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . Before coming to DBMS part , i am getting error while fetching refcursor variable to the local variables . its says its 'Invalid cursor '.Do we need to open that cursor ?. The procedure returns multiple values through OUT variable using SYS_REFCURSOR datatype. Your code is same as my code .

Comment: You're welcome. My example shows how to do that. You don't have to *open* any cursor (as my code demonstrates).

Comment: Thanks much for the example , but i am thinking what could be the reason for this error in my case .  if i remove the loop part completely the block works . only problem arises while fetching into local variables .

Comment: Can some one conform if the OUT SYS_REFCURSOR not returns any values will lead to 'INVALID CURSOR' error ?

Comment: @user1402648 no, a cursor fetch not returning a row doesn't make it invalid and isn't an exception condition.